# C write data after 1024 lines in a csv file

Tags: c, csv, printf

I am trying to write data in `csv` file per 1024 lines:

```
fprintf(fp, "%f %f \1024n", a, b)
```

what is the right way to write per `1024` lines?

Comment: What is the maximum length of each line? Assuming below 999, use `int i=0;char line[1000]; while(fgets(line,sizeof line,fp)){ i++; if(i==1024){ /*Write to file*/ i=0;} }`

Comment: `char linesgalore[1025]; memset(linesgalore, '\n', 1024); linesgalore[1024] = 0; /* ... */ fputs(linesgalore, fp);`

Comment: @CoolGuy: the behavior of `fgets` on reading a too long line is documented, and for stress testing I often write my routines to use a "too small" buffer -- and when it works, I change the buffer to a reasonable size. It's quite a long routine; in this case I'd settle for a `fgetc` loop.

Comment: Note that the question may be how to *insert* a line into an existing text file. That is not a straightforward task.

Comment: @Jongware , "*the behavior of `fgets` on reading a too long line is documented*" -- Could you explain more on this?

Comment: @CoolGuy: "Parsing stops if end-of-file occurs or a newline character is found, in which case `str` will contain that newline character." (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) so when the buffer may be too small for the current line, simply call `fgets` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to use a loop:

```
int i=0;
for(i=0; i<1024;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%f %f\n", a, b);
}
```

Secondly add a semicolon between values. This grants that csv will be opened automatically by excel dividing values in colums:

```
int i=0;
for(i=0; i<1024;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, "%f;%f\n", a, b);
}
```

**Edit**
To leave 1024 empty lines you can do

```
int i=0;
fprintf(fp, "%f;%f\n", a, b); // print a nd b values
// this loop write 1024 empty lines
for(i=0; i<1024;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
}
```

Comment: by per 1024 I mean that I want to write to the 1st line leave the next 1024 empty and then write again, I use a for loop but the point is not that I want to write 1024 lines in the row

Comment: thanks if I want to both write two values and leave 1024 lines I do:
 
        
 int i=0;
for(i=0; i<1024;i++)
{
fprintf(fp, "%f;%f\n", a, b);    
fprintf(fp, "\n");
} ???

Comment: No. That code write 1024 * 2 lines. Even lines with a and b values, and odd lines empty. I edited

Comment: thanks then I will put a for loop inside a for loop and if I want to store comma separated data I need to put , between "%f,%f" or ;?

Comment: That's the way. Use, as shown a semicolon, non a comma. Check the question as answered to avoid other people waste time to read all.